# Eclipse: C++ Run Configuration missing?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Good day,

I set up Eclipse with MinGW and my project compiles fine:

[image]

However when I try to run it via creating a *Run Configuration* I have the problem that there is no *C/C++ Local Application* like here:

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

What is missed? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select Help → Install New Software
2. Type this url:http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo
3. Tick the CDT Main Features witch includes c++ sdk
4. Restart eclipse done!

Answer (score 2):

Local C/C++ Application in the latest versions appears to have been renamed to C/C++ Application:

Just simply click on Run As -> Local Application
[image]

And now a run configuration should have appeared under C/C++ Application
[image]

---

After reading your question again I realised I misunderstood it. Anyhow, it looks as if you're using Eclipse instead of [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php). You may want to download CDT version of Eclipse and give it another try.